# DNS: Forward domain to another host

Tags: dns, cname

I have a domain that is hosted with XO Communications. I want to host that domain at another web host, but I want to keep the mail at XO, so I'd like to keep the DNS managed by XO. What do I need to do in the DNS to switch it the website to the other host, but leave the mail unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the DNS records and set the A record for www.example.com to the IP-address of the hosting server at a.n.other web-hosting service. Keep the MX records pointing to the names of XO's SMTP servers.

Comment: FYI, MX records must point to *names*, never IP addresses

Comment: Setting the A-record for www.example.com doesn't forward example.com, does it? Any way to do both?

Comment: @normmcgarry: set up one A record for each name. That's two A records. Each with the same IP-address.

Comment: @grawity: thanks for pointing out the mistake, I'll correct the answer.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. I'm at the mercy of the XO interface though, which doesn't seem to allow me to only add an A-record of example.com. Must have a subdomain.